# User accessing Windows share keeps receiving username/password request (across OpenVPN if that's relevant)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, openvpn, windows-authentication

At my work, we have set up an OpenVPN system for our remote users to access the machines in the office.  The office machines are set up on a domain.  I have created a domain user for her.

A new employee is having difficulty accessing the servers.  She connects to the VPN successfully, but then can't actually do anything with it.

- If she types in \servername, a username/password box comes up.  If she enters the username and password I've given her, it thinks for a minute then displays the username/password request again.  It doesn't give her any error message, just asks for a password again.
- If she tries to access the system using Remote Desktop, she gets as far as the login screen, and when she tries to enter it, the machine gives her "Username/password incorrect".

These both occur whether she enters the username as "username" or "domain\username".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If she can access the server via RDC and it displays wrong username and password I don't think it has anything to do with the OpenVPN connection but rather her credentials. I would check to make sure her username, password and domain are correct.

Comment: Apparently I will never be a tech support person.  The thought that she might be typing the password incorrectly was the *last*, rather than *first* thought...  :$